# Using PHP PDO is it possible to bind a parameter to be used by a MySQL function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

Inside MySQL I have a function named *GetLongitude* and I'm trying do to this without success.

First try:

```
$sql = "select GetLongitude(:cidade) as lon;";
$stmt = $dbHandle->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Second try:

```
$sql = "select GetLongitude(?) as lon;";
$dbHandle->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
$stmt = $dbHandle->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($cidade));
```

(The sql above is just a simple example.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not? A placeholder is a placeholder. It should work. First example is better made.

Comment: `as lon;` that semi-colon's an issue here, for one thing.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How is the semi-colon an issue? It's just terminating the statement, so unneeded, but as far as I know, it shouldn't break the query.

Comment: @aynber You could be right. The question's incomplete, far as I'm concerned. They want us to "fill in the blanks" in order to "test it for them".

Comment: With PDO the semi-colon is not *generally* an issue. YMMV